# Db context - multiple usages

Tags: c#, entity-framework

so I stumbled upon a weird thing just now.
I have a test which changes the `until` date of a `workingsite` to yesterday like so:

```
using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var empFromDb = db.Employees.Include(x => x.WorkingSites).First(x => x.Id == _employeeId);
            empFromDb.WorkingSites.Add(workingSiteToEnd);
            db.SaveChanges();

        //Act
        ServiceFactory.CreateEmployeeService().EndWorkingSitePeriod(workingSiteToEnd);

        //Assert
            var workingSiteFromDb = db.WorkingSites.First(x => x.Id == workingSiteToEnd.Id);

            Assert.AreEqual(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date, workingSiteFromDb.WorksUntil.Date);
        }
```

In this test my assert fails and the `until` hasn't changed for the object `workingSiteFromDb`, yet in my code I do change it and save changes to the database.
**note**: my database *did* update! I checked inside the database and the date is altered correctly.

Now I didn't know what was going on and so I stopped the `using` right after the first `savechanges` and opened it again right before I call `workingSiteFromDb`.

If I do this, it works.

Note that I use another `using` within the `EndWorkingSitePeriod` method.

How come my database does update but the object only updates when I use a second `using`?

This is the `EndWorkingSitePeriod` method:

```
public void EndWorkingSitePeriod(int workingSiteId)
    {
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var workingSiteFromDb = db.WorkingSites.Include(x => x.Employee).First(x => x.Id == workingSiteId);
            workingSiteFromDb.EndPeriod();
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

The `workingSite.EndPeriod` just sets the `UntilDate`to `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)`

Comment: can you show the code for EndWorkingSitePeriod()?

Comment: Updated the question to show this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're obtaining `workingSiteToEnd` somewhere and adding it to context, created in 1st line of your sample. Then, you're saving the changes (`workingSiteToEnd` now in the database **and** in the context).

Then, you're creating the second context in `EndWorkingSitePeriod` method. Using that context, you're obtaining **new** `workingSiteFromDb` instance (it doesn't relate to `workingSiteToEnd` from above). You're modifying it, and saving changes.

Now, you're trying to test the changes you've made, but **original** `workingSiteToEnd` is still present in context. This means, that when you'll try to load it from database again, context, during materialization process, will look up for entity with the same key in its local cache, will find it, and will return existing entity, which is **original**, unchanged `workingSiteToEnd` (you can compare references, they'll be equal).

When you're closing `using` block right after first `SaveChanges`, and then creating new one, you're creating **new** context, which will load new instance for `workingSiteFromDb`, and the test will pass.

Comment: A colleague of mine also just told me that this was only the case when using `Find` through `Linq` and that `First` would go to the database again **but** using `Find` if possible is much better. Thank you for this answer. This explains the issue just great.

Answer (score 0):

Do not nest usings of the same DbContext. Instead, if you need to use the same context in called method, pass it with parameter, e.g.:

```
using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
   var empFromDb = db.Employees.Include(x => x.WorkingSites).First(x => x.Id == _employeeId);
   empFromDb.WorkingSites.Add(workingSiteToEnd);
   db.SaveChanges();

   //Act
   ServiceFactory.CreateEmployeeService().EndWorkingSitePeriod(workingSiteToEnd, db);

   //Assert
   var workingSiteFromDb = db.WorkingSites.First(x => x.Id == workingSiteToEnd.Id);

   Assert.AreEqual(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date, workingSiteFromDb.WorksUntil.Date);
}

private void EndWorkingSitePeriod(int workingSiteId, ApplicationDbContext db)
{
    var workingSiteFromDb = db.WorkingSites.Include(x => x.Employee).First(x => x.Id == workingSiteId);
    workingSiteFromDb.EndPeriod();
    db.SaveChanges();
}

// if you need it public, then use this too
public void EndWorkingSitePeriod(int workingSiteId)
{
    using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext()) 
    {
       EndWorkingSitePeriod(workingSiteId, db);
    }
}
```

Comment: since I'm going through a test, I am not going to pass my applicationDbContext on this.